# Running SSRS Report by passing parameters in the URL doesn't show any result of the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I'm trying to run an SSRS report on the server which takes a parameter as input. When I enter input in the textbox it displays the result. Also works fine in the visual studio BIDS.
But, I want to pass parameter in the URL and see the report result which is not working.

I have seen solutions to other similar SO posts [SSRS passing Report Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650508/ssrs-passing-report-parameters)
which mentioned checking the dataset parameters properties.
My parameter name is **@TestId** and value is set to **=Parameters!TestId.Value**
So, it is correct as suggested in the solution.

Now I try o access my report using URL patterns as below

**Just giving parameter and value**
http://testssrs14/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fTest%2fTestReport%2fTest+Report&TestId=1234

**using command = render**
http://testssrs/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fTest%2fTestReport%2fTest+Report&rs:Command=Render&TestId=1234

when I hit enter it doesn't throw any error in both cases but just shows a blank page instead of the result of the report. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I guess you are trying to access your reports from _Report Manager_ , try from  _report server_ instead, and then pass on the values, same, as you have tried so far.

Comment: What browser are you using? (Chrome will render blank, IE will work).  If you are in Chrome, you can confirm by running it, and exporting to a file once run.  If file has data then it's a browser issue.

Comment: @GandRalph, I'm not using Chrome, running on IE. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Irf, I'm using report server.

Comment: So when you hit the export button and save the report to Excel for example, the excel doc is empty? (Confirming there is indeed no data)

Comment: @LearnCodeFun Cannot post an image in here, I mean are you trying to access your reports like from here [as shown in the image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzg8dbh1CrN9TFc0X3pyc19hZmc) ??, just to confirm

Comment: Have you tried adding &ViewMode=Detail to the end of the URL?

Comment: @LearnCodeFun Why I am asking so, is because I can see that the URL your have posted, in post, suggests like, the report is kinda being attempted to be accessed from Report Manager, which is a part of, of-course, reporting services.. Sorry, if it doesn't make that sense, am just trying to figure out what the actual cause is

Comment: @GandRalph, I'm just trying to view the report in the browser itself, not in any excel doc. The report has data (confirmed by giving value in input text box and also in BIDS). I haven't tried adding &ViewMode=Detai. Will try that.

Comment: @Irf, How do I differentiate between manager and server? I don't see any manager in my report server

Comment: as @Irf was trying to point out, your URL is like this `http://testssrs14/Reports/Pages....` but you need to access it as `http://testssrs14/Reportserver/Pages....`

Comment: Take a look at the answer @LearnCodeFun,  and tell me if it solves your issue, and as Alan has suggested, that's how your URL must be like

Comment: Did my attempt to answer help you anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this URL instead and try

```
 http://testssrs14/ReportServer/
```

And navigate to the report that you're looking for.

When you get to the report page, then pass the parameter value.

```
&<Parameter Name> = <value>
```

In your case

```
&TestId=1234
```

Add this at the end of the URL.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, Here's some detail.. though I guess it must be figured out as of now..

Here goes the report server:

[image: report server]

and **below** goes the Report Manager..

[image: Report Manager]

and in VS Data Tools or BIDS, the same is set as in  `Projects->Properties` **below**

[image: VS Data Tools]

So, you got to try your URL parameters in *ReportServer*, not in **Report Manager**.
What you had been accessing so far is **Report Manager**..

Hope it makes some sense, now : ) ,

Thus, your link should be something like `http://testssrs14/Reportserver/..`

[This link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/) is also a good source!